# Click not making it to the document

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an event that is not reaching all the way down to the document.  The result of this means the jQuery code and server side c# code doesn't execute.  I have tracked the event all the way to the ul where it stops.  How can this be rectified?  attached is an abbreviated code sample so show the hierarchy.

So what happens the user clicks on **ctl00_cphBody_rTracks_ctl00_lbStatusClass2** the event bubbles up to the **span**, then to the **li**, and last to the **ul**.  then the event is somehow cancelled.

```
<body onload="javascript: AddTHEAD('gvPrint')" onclick="alert('body');">    
...
    <div onclick="alert('div content');" class="content">
        <div onclick="alert('div container');" class="container">
        ...    
        <div onclick="alert('playlist custom');" class="playlist custom">
         ...
            <ul id="ulPlaylist" onclick="alert('ul admin-left');" class="admin-left">
                ...
            <li onclick="alert('li admin-song ui-selectee');" class='admin-song ui-selectee ' mediaid="4068484" artistid="257903"><span class="handle">
                ... 
                <span onclick="alert('span-remove');" id="spanStatus" class="remove"><a id="ctl00_cphBody_rTracks_ctl00_lbStatusClass2" class="btn-del" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphBody$rTracks$ctl00$lbStatusClass2','')">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this should be solved by using the UNSELECTABLE="on" attribute . I had a similar kind of issue which worked after i included the unselectable attribute. The reason could be that the event dies out when it is bubbled up to span/li/ul. Could you please try including this property for span,li and ul and check if it works as expected. you can refer the below link to find more details on the UNSELECTABLE attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537840(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work.  I attached the unselectable="on" attribute but it didn't change anything.  The click stops when it gets to the ul still.